# Frappe Bench non-www to www

Tags: nginx, erpnext, frappe

How to redirect non-www to www website on Frappe Bench ERPNext solution?

I have a website www.example.com setup and working properly on ERPNext Frappe Bench but now I want example.com to load www.example.com but it shows error site_config not found, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to setup just `example.com` on your Frappe Bench. Then setup your DNS by adding a CNAME to point `www.example.com` to `example.com`. You can do this on the site of the service you use to host your domain name.